# How to deploy and angular app using GitHubActions to EC2 with Yarn as the package manager?

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, yaml, github-actions

I have written a yaml script with a help of a blog that contains all the necessary work that needs to be carried out in order to deploy my application to an ec2 instance running ubuntu. NGINX has been installed and is running.
Unfortunately, my yaml script fails silently, I do not know what is wrong, here is the code that's in the script

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request: 
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    # using Ubuntu
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "18.x"

      - name: Run install
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v4 
        with:
          cmd: install
      - name: Install Angular CLI
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v4
        with:
          cmd: yarn global add @angular/cli
      - name: Build production bundle
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v4
        with:
          cmd: build:prod # will run `yarn build:prod` command

      - name: Deploy to my EC2 instance
        uses: easingthems/ssh/deploy@2.1.5
        with: 
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: $ {{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }} # I have the SSH_Private key of the instance saved as secrets in GitHub under the repository settings.
          SOURCE: "dist/my-client-app"
          REMOTE_HOST: "my-remote-host" # here I used my instances's IP Address. Not sure if that is what I am supposed to put there.
          REMOTE_USER: "ubuntu"
          TARGET: "/var/www/html/my-client-app"
```

Can anyone point out what could be the issue here?

Comment: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-24-github-actions-re-run-jobs-with-debug-logging/#:~:text=You%20can%20now%20enable%20debug,in%20the%20re%2Drun%20dialog.

Comment: why to EC2 and not S3 ?

Comment: Isn't that for storage? @mar0ne

Comment: not only storage, if you have a static website you can use S3 to deploy it. Under the hood there is nginx that will be serving it.

Comment: I'll give you the code that deploys angular app to S3 in the answer section. S3 is much easier and much cheaper than EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of workflow that build, test and deploy angular app to AWS S3:

```
jobs:
  build-test-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 16

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install

    - name: test # this section runs tests
      run: npm run test

    - name: Build
      run: npm run build

    - name: Deploy
      if: success()
      run: aws s3 sync ./dist/app/ s3://your-bucket-name
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to let you know that I ended up using Amplify, which was a lot easier. At the end non of the recommended answers worked. The linux ubuntu EC2 was still giving me issues. It escalated to ng build not found but the environment had everything set so yaa.